# Remote debugging Java application

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting the following message when I try to remote debug a java application through eclipse.
"Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused."
What could be the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke the process to be debugged with the appropriate options e.g.

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

(substitute with the appropriate port if necessary) and it sounds like the VM isn't listening on the configured port. You can use `netstat /a` to confirm if the VM is listening on that port (or `telnet`)

Comment: When I tried netstat /a i got: 
TCP    DEV-MACHINE2:8787      localhost:1261         ESTABLISHED
This is the only entry for the port number 8787 which I an using.

Answer (score 2):

For client debugging, I came across the same issue

```
URL -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4081
```

Changing the port number solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

do you have port 8000, or whatever port you have configured for remote connections open on your firewall?

Comment: Right now I'm testing on my machine. So it won't be a problem right?

Answer (score 1):

The remote application needs to be started first. Did you add the arguments to the target remote app so it will accept a debugging connection/

Comment: Sometimes the port hasn't been released from the last time it was ran. On Windows do a 'netstat -a' and look for the port the remote app is using to listen for debug connections. If it is still open, you won't be able to open a remote debug session. Close the port/socket or if it comes down to it, change the port used. Hopefully the first socket eventually releases before you lock up the second.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your JVM was started with these options

> -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n

and that port 8000 is free

Comment: just do a netstat -an | grep 8000

Answer (score 0):

With the newer JDKs you might also need to specify address=*:8000 so that it listens for remote connections.